How to display "3 of 10 files" using localizedAdditionalDescription of NSProgress
I would like to utilize NSProgress localizedAdditionalDescription but I cannot figure out the combination to get it to format file count. Either i am not getting any suffix or I get bytes.
progress.kind: File

Processing 15 files…
5 bytes of 20 bytes

progress.kind: None
25 % completed
5 of 20

let progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 20)
progress.completedUnitCount = 5

progress.setUserInfoObject(10, forKey: ProgressUserInfoKey.fileCompletedCountKey)
progress.setUserInfoObject(15, forKey: ProgressUserInfoKey.fileTotalCountKey)

print("progress.kind: File")
progress.kind = .file
print(progress.localizedDescription)
print(progress.localizedAdditionalDescription)

print("progress.kind: None")
progress.kind = .none
print(progress.localizedDescription)
print(progress.localizedAdditionalDescription)



totalUnitCount must be zero, in addition to kind being .file, to get progress by files. You can set the fileTotalCount and fileCompletedCount directly rather than through the user info object.
let progress = Progress()
progress.kind = .file
progress.fileCompletedCount = 5
progress.fileTotalCount = 20
print(progress.localizedAdditionalDescription)

Output:
Optional("5 of 20 files")


Cannot believe I missed this. Fighting it so hard. Thanks!

The key to get this information is to reset NSProgressByteTotalCountKey and NSProgressByteCompletedCountKey to 0
On top you can use fractionCompleted observation, isFinished etc.
progress.setUserInfoObject(0, forKey: ProgressUserInfoKey("NSProgressByteTotalCountKey"))
progress.setUserInfoObject(0, forKey: ProgressUserInfoKey("NSProgressByteCompletedCountKey"))

Result:
progress.kind: File
Processing 15 files…
10 of 15 files
progress.kind: None
25 % completed
10 of 15 files

Bonus: If you use NSProgressUseItemDescriptionKey you can change files to items
progress.setUserInfoObject(true, forKey: ProgressUserInfoKey("NSProgressUseItemDescriptionKey"))

Result:
progress.kind: File
Processing 15 items…
10 of 15 items
progress.kind: None
25 % completed
10 of 15 items

